# Timer Field in CRM Dynamics 2015

Tags: datetime, timer, case, crm, dynamics-crm-2015

I am currently working on Dynamics CRM 2015 with Timer field. As per the requirements when a case is created it will go through 2 departments
. (department 1 and then Department 2). Each department has its Separate TAT (Turn Around Time). When Case is assigned to department 1 , I have 
used crm Timer functionality behind it which takes "case start time(created on in my case) + TAT(Turn around time) as an input and starts it self.

Lets assume I have assigned the case record to department 1 whose TAT is 2 Hours:
The case is created on 4:00 PM so the Timer end time will be 6:00 PM. As soon as I created the case ,Timer for Department 1 Starts.

Now if I fwd my case to department 2 on 5:00 PM. (In this case Department 1 timer should paused on "1 Hr" which is its consumed time.)

Similarly to department 1 I have TAT for Department 2 as well for 2 hours.

Now lets assume that department 2 is not satisfied about the work that department 1 has completed and he wants to assign
the case back to Department 1.

I want my department 1 timer to resume from 1 hr and complete its remaining time.

Any thoughts how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

- Please define the **SLA** for the specific departments.
- Do all the configurations required for SLA calculations for the two departments.
- Now add 2 status values in the status field of Case entities e.g. Case at Department 1 and Case at Department 2.
- Go to the `Settings --> service management --> Service configuration settings`
- Select Tab Service and add the two newly created values to the On Hold status list.